# "If" - "Else" in Mod Rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite

I've been searching and testing for 3 hours and no luck. Hopefully you al can help me.

Here is my code:

```
AddHandler php-legacy .php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://www\.google\.com [NC]
RewriteRule http://www.domain1.com [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.domain2.com/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .*
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://$1.domain2.com/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

The second mod_rewrite works and has been working for months, but now I want to check first and see if someone is visiting from Google. If so, I want to push them to a different domain. But the (1st) referrer part does not. How do I check the referrer and act on it "before" I run the second part?

A second question. I don't think you can anymore, but is there any way to tell if someone is coming from a Google Adwords link or an Organic Search link? I think Google has made this impossible.

Answer (score 1):

You've got an error in your `RewriteRule`, it looks like you're missing the regular expression match.

```
RewriteRule http://www.domain1.com [R=301,L]
```

Is going to make apache think:

- if the URI is `http://www.domain1.com`
- rewrite it to `[R=301,L]`

You probably want this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain1.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Tried your code and no luck. No error, it just ignores the referrer.